org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Database connection failed during resolving unknown type
I'm using Kafka Connect with the Debezium PostgreSQL connector to stream data changes, and I'm encountering an error that causes the task to fail and not recover automatically. The error seems related to a prepared statement conflict in PostgreSQL. Below is the relevant portion of the log:
2024-10-08 12:04:39 2024-10-08 05:04:39,928 ERROR  ||  WorkerSourceTask{id=postgres-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
2024-10-08 12:04:39 org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Database connection failed during resolving unknown type
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.TypeRegistry.resolveUnknownType(TypeRegistry.java:404)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.TypeRegistry.get(TypeRegistry.java:179)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresType$Builder.build(PostgresType.java:304)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.TypeRegistry.prime(TypeRegistry.java:338)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.TypeRegistry.<init>(TypeRegistry.java:125)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresConnection.<init>(PostgresConnection.java:106)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.lambda$start$1(PostgresConnectorTask.java:95)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.jdbc.DefaultMainConnectionProvidingConnectionFactory.<init>(DefaultMainConnectionProvidingConnectionFactory.java:16)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.start(PostgresConnectorTask.java:94)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:141)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.initializeAndStart(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:280)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:77)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:236)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2024-10-08 12:04:39 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: prepared statement "S_1" already exists
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:368)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:498)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:415)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.TypeRegistry.loadType(TypeRegistry.java:409)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.TypeRegistry.resolveUnknownType(TypeRegistry.java:400)
2024-10-08 12:04:39     ... 19 more

my docker compose file:
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: quay.io/debezium/zookeeper:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: quay.io/debezium/kafka:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
  kafka-ui:
    container_name: kafka-ui
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    links:
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 9089:8080
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092

  postgres:
    image: quay.io/debezium/example-postgres:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
      - 6543:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=***
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***

  connect:
    image: quay.io/debezium/connect:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    links:
      - kafka
      - postgres
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses

my connect.json file:
{
  "name": "postgres-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "***",
    "database.port": "***",
    "database.user": "***",
    "database.password": "****",
    "database.dbname": "postgres",
    "topic.prefix": "dbserver1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "snapshot.mode": "always",
    "table.include.list": "public.clinics",
    "database.slot.name": "debezium_slot"
  }
}

Has anyone encountered this error before or knows what might cause Debezium to conflict with prepared statements in PostgreSQL?
Checked for any cached prepared statements in PostgreSQL, but no long-running statements were found.
Tried restarting the connector, but the issue reoccurs consistently.
Searched for potential issues with PostgreSQL’s type resolution, but I haven’t found a clear answer yet.

You are using a connection pool, and Debezium doesn't expect it. No idea what you need to do to make it work, but that's the cause of the problem.
